# How to add GitHub's Mantle to Xcode using CocoaPods

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, github-mantle

I have added GitHub's [Mantle](https://github.com/github/Mantle) project to a iOS 6 project using [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/):

```
$ pod search Mantle
$ vim Podfile // here I added pod 'Mantle'
$ pod install // this installs Mantle 1.0
```

Then I have added the `($inherited)` variable to the `Header Search Paths` of project's 'Build Settings' section, **before** my custom search paths. When importing the Mantle header file Xcode complains with

```
#import "Mantle.h" // => 'Mantle/MTLJSONAdapter.h' file not found
```

Am I missing some step? I have other pods installed as well (AFNetworking and SSKeychain) but only Mantle is giving me issues.

I have also added SSToolkit but following the instructions on its 'Getting started', i.e. not using CocoaPods.

Comment: I don't know if I should answer or comment. Nothing worked at first, so I went to manually install like MailCore or any other library. Also failed, then I noticed this line: "Mantle requires submodules so it is not supported via CocoaPods officially". So basically, unless you get lucky, you have to use git to add it, then init submodules. or copy from a dir that has the submodules I would bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the problem seemed to be related with the Xcode project/workspace configuration I tried all kind of 'cleaning' solutions:

1. Delete the `Pods` directory, the `Podfile.lock` file and install everything from scratch.
2. Delete the `MyProject.xcworkspace` directory and repeat step 1
3. Enter `MyProject.xcodeproj`, delete `project.xcworkspace` and `xcuserdata` directories and repeat step 1.
4. Go to the global Xcode directory (`/Users/my_user/Library/Developer/Xcode`), remove everything related to the project, specially the `DerivedData` subdirectory, and repeat step 1.

The final step seems to be the final solution, though I cannot tell which file/folder removal did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added Mantle to your `Podfile`? You mention running `pod install Mantle` which doesn't/shouldn't do anything but show an error. (`[!] Unrecognized argument:`Mantle'`)

After you add Mantle to your Podfile and run `pod install` you should be able to link `Mantle.h` directly and there will be a few directories in your `xcworkspace` and the `Pods` project. After this you can use `#import "Mantle.h"` no issues.

[image: Example]

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy-paste typo. I have `pod 'Mantle'` added to my Podfile and the command is just `pod install`.

Comment: @elitalon ok good. Does your `Pods` project look like the screenshot?

Comment: Yep, I have a Mantle group below Pods just as your screenshot. In fact, I have other pods installed as well (AFNetworking and SSKeychain). Only Mantle is giving me issues

Comment: @elitalon try deleting your `Podfile.lock` and the `Pods` folder. Then run `pod install` again.

Comment: No success either. I'm thinking of adding Mantle by hand as with SSToolkit if this continues to give problems

Comment: @elitalon that's very strange since it worked perfectly for my install. What are your issues with SSToolKit?

Comment: @elitalon try removing the build flag you added. You shouldn't need that with Cocoapods

Comment: I have no issues with SSToolkit, just followed the 'Getting started' guide to add it instead of using Cocoapods: http://sstoolk.it/#getting-started But I had to add `MyProject/Vendor/SSToolkit` instead of `Vendor/SSTolkit`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the problem appears to simply be that my Mantle pod was too old. Changed version to '2.0.5' and pod updated, things work fine.